# How can I respond programmatically to Excel Chart changes of all kinds?

Tags: vba, events, excel, charts

Excel has VBA event handlers for when you change a chart's size (`Resize`) or one of its series (`SeriesChange`) or the data it uses (`Calculate`) but seemingly not for any other type of change for example:

- Axis settings
- Label text
- Legend positioning

Changes to charts embedded in a worksheet don't fire the worksheet's `Change` event either.

Is there any way at all to capture these events?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Chart_MouseDown` event, then check if anything has changed

Comment: Not all chart changes are triggered by mouse events, and especially not immediately after a direct click on the chart.